# <div asp-validation-summary> does not work - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC to add validation errors to a form,

```
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

seems to work but the method that I am being taught,

```
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
```

does not render the error messages for some reason. Not sure whether this is an issue with the version of  ASP.NET MVC that I am using, although I believe I clicked 'ASP.NET Core Web Application' when I started the project? How can I check whether this is an MVC Core project or just a normal MVC project?

Other code:

//My model:

```
    public class GuestResponse
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your phone number")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify whether you'll attend")]
        public bool? WillAttend { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks,

Rob

[image]

Comment: Several ways of finding out. Do you have a class called `Startup`?

Comment: Right click on the project and select properties. Select Application from the Tab left side. Check Target Framework if .Net Core is selected or .Net Framework.

Comment: It says .Net Framework. I'm going to start a blank .Net Core project and then create the blank files and copy over the code.

Answer (score 0):

some time validation summary does not work because developer does not add reference of unobtrsuve.min.js in application. when you include this reference it will fire validation